# React JS: How to iterate hashmap in React js

Tags: reactjs

I have created hashmap with key,List as values am trying to iterate the map with forEach. I could not able to display values on browser, but Ii could able to see values in console.

**code am using to iterate the map inside render method:**

```js
this.state.map2.forEach(function(value, key) {
   value.map(passCode=>(<div>
      {passCode.disptext}
   </div>))
})
```

Can some help to display the values on browser? or is there any better way to iterate the map.

Answer (score 2):

react needs a key on the dom element in the map function. the key should be unique

```
this.state.map2.forEach(function(value, key) {
   value.map(passCode=>(<div key = {passCode.dispText + key}>
      {passCode.disptext}
   </div>))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Map and Set in react state is not recommended because they are optimized for Mutability while React discourages it specially in state.

Specific to your case; you are trying to output list so you have to use [List tags](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp)

This can be one way to doing this:

```
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props)
this.state = {
    items: [
    { text: ["Learn JavaScript"] },
    { text: ["Learn react"] },
    { text: ["Learn node"]},
    { text: ["Learn vue"] }
  ]
}
}

render() {
return (
  <div>
    <h2>Todos:</h2>
    <ol>
    {this.state.items.map(item => (
      <li key={item.id}>
          <span>{item.text}</span>
      </li>
    ))}
    </ol>
  </div>
)
}
}
```